# categorize hashtags into topics or categories. example: #FIFA -> SPORTS , VIDEO_GAMES

Tags: nlp, classification, text-processing

Is there a public API or Java library that would classify Twitter Hashtags into a topics/categories from a finite set.

I need to find the topic of each twitter post based on their hashtags. For example:

/#FIFA12 would classify this post as VIDEO_GAMES/GAMES or ENTERTAINMENT, etc.

Comment: Sounds like a fun project if there isn't one.  You could build a bag-of-words vector for each tweet, cluster the vectors into k clusters, and then, for tweets in the same cluster, say that the hashtags in those tweets make up a single category.  Of course you'd have to name the categories manually.

Comment: thanks for the reply!, can you give a simple example. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of an API to do this, but one  way would be to look at hashtags that map to Wikipedia titles. E.g. There is a "FIFA12" title in Wikipedia (that redirects to a different page). Barring ambiguous strings, you should be able to map a large number of hashtags to Wikipedia titles.

Once you have the titles, you can traverse the Wikipedia graph and obtain parent-child category relations. E.g. FIFA12 is categorized in Wikipedia under the following categories.

```
2011 video games
Electronic Arts games
EA Sports games
PlayStation 2 games
PlayStation 3 games
PlayStation Portable games
IOS games
Xbox 360 games
Wii games
Nintendo 3DS games
Windows games
Video games developed in Canada
Association football video games
Sports video games with career mode
Video games set in 2011
```

Each of these categories will have more parents. E.g. "2011 video games" has the parents

```
2011 works
21st-century video games
2011 in video gaming
2011 software
```

You can probably use a "majority vote" with a threshold (say 2+) at each level of breadth-first search to reduce the number of nodes you need to analyze . At some point, you can come up with a heuristic to stop. E.g. the category "Video games" is three hops away from FIFA12 and is reachable via more than one path. Coming up with the optimal heuristic is not trivial but there is quite some low hanging fruit here.

Comment: This is a nice approach, the only issue is that not all hashtags have a corresponding wiki page.

Comment: That is correct. However if you think of a hashtag broadly as a "concept", the intersection should be huge given that Wikipedia has millions of concepts.